# Javascript: Find string in first few letters

Tags: javascript

I would like to find the first a string in a string. I know it is not clear, so i decided to give an example.

For example, i got a string:

> helloworld,hello

In "helloworld,hello", i want the system to find "hello" and ignore "world,hello". Is that possible?

If my question is unclear, do not refrain from asking me.

Thank you.

Please show me an example on how it works on jsfiddle.

Comment: How do you define the string? Meaningful word?

Comment: What do you want to do with it ?

Comment: Give another example, I think it'd make things clearer.

Comment: Lets say the string is "hellogooddayhello". I want the machine to check if hello is found in the first few letters of the string.

Comment: @Deximat what do you mean?

Comment: @RCV your comment is unrelated to the question. My purpose is totally unrelated to what i am asking.

Comment: @leonneo I didn't know you know content of the string, since you solved the problem there is no problem :)

Comment: @Deximat I got what you meant know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without knowing what the content of the string will be. If you do know it, you could parse it with regex, like this: `var patt1=/hello/;`. This would find the first occurrence of hello.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x7WVP/

Comment: can you please share it on jsfiddle?

Comment: Yours is clearly explained and with an example, you deserved it.

Answer (score 1):

Do Try this:

```
"helloworld,hello".match(/hello/).toString();
```